# Creating a loop to subset data using R

Tags: r, loops, subset

This is a sample of my dataframe. I have three years, three states, and six roles. I would like to subset my dataframe so that I have a new dataframe for every combination of year and state for all six roles.

```
> A[1:10,c(1,4,64:69)]
   Year State Role1 Role2 Role3 Role4 Role5 Role6
1  2010   1     1     0     1     1     0     0
2  2012   3     1     0     0     1     0     0
3  2010   2     1     0     0     1     0     0
4  2011   1     1     0     0     1     0     0
5  2011   3     0     1     0     1     0     0
6  2010   2     1     0     0     1     0     0
7  2010   2     0     1     0     1     0     0
8  2012   2     0     1     0     1     0     0
9  2012   2     0     0     0     0     0     1
10 2011   1     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

I could do something like this and repeat it for all combinations:

```
2010_1_Role1 <- subset(A, Year=="2010" & State=="1" & Role1=="1")
2011_1_Role1 <- subset(A, Year=="2011" & State=="1" & Role1=="1")
2012_1_Role1 <- subset(A, Year=="2012" & State=="1" & Role1=="1")
```

...I don't have a lot of experience writing loops, but I figured there's probably a faster way to do it writing a for loop! Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `split` to give a `list` of `data.frame` for all the unique combinations of the groups

```
lst1 <- split(A, A[c("Year", "State", "Role1")], drop = TRUE)
```

and then do all the transformations within the `list` using `lapply/sapply`

It is not recommended to have multiple objects in the global environment.  If we need,

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

after changing the names of the `list` with the preferred object names.

---

It is not clear why we need to subset.  If this is to execute some code over each group, then a `group_by` operation is preferrable

```
library(dplyr)
A %>%
  group_b(Year, State, Role1) %>%
  mutate(Colname = yourfun(Colname))
  # or for summarise
  # summarise(n = n())
```